# Implement intersection products

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, tag-removed

I am doing a counting problem, and it comes to compute intersection products ( Chow ring ) on some varieties. Is there any computer algebra that deals with this?

Comment: If not, then see here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/18440/

Comment: Also, many enumeration problems deal with toric varieties, for which see here: http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1243161

Answer (score 5):

Schubert2 in [Macaulay2](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/) and the original maple package [schubert](http://folk.uib.no/nmajo/schubert/) let you build enough of the chow rings of parameter spaces to tackle some enumerative geometry problems like those of "Kalkül der abzählenden Geometrie" by H. Schubert (1879):

#### Count the number of space conics intersecting 8 given lines

> > with(schubert):
>
> > grass(3,4,d,all):
>
> > Proj(f,dual(symm(2,Qd)),e):
>
> > integral(Gd,lowerstar(f,(2*d1+e)^8));
>
> ```
>                                   92
> ```

(Example 3.2.22 of "Intersection Theory" by W. Fulton (1984))

Answer (score 2):

It would help to know the context of your work better - what category are you working in?

I currently work computing arithmetic (Arakelov) intersection pairings on curves, for which I use magma, doing the actual calculations using either resultants or Grobner bases (at least at finite primes); all you are calculating are the lengths of modules, which is fairly standard for commutative algebra software I assume.

Answer (score 1):

For Grassmannians, see Buch's [Littlewood-Richardson calculator](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~asbuch/lrcalc/). Buch [quantum calculator](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~asbuch/qcalc/) can compute quantum cohomology (and hence ordinary) on grassmannians, isotropic grassmannians and symplectic isotoropic grassmannians. [Symmetrica](http://orms.mfo.de/project?terms=polynomial&id=307) can compute Schubert polynomials, and hence should be able to be coerced into computing in the cohomology ring of the flag manifold, although I don't know how easy or hard that is.